# Realtime Display of Data

Tags: c++, qt, software-design, architecture

I am designing an application to collect my vehicles data and display it on an application.  I'm trying to figure out what the best archtitecure of my software would be.  I plan on using Qt for my gui (QPainter) and I have custom hardware that collects the data from sensors.  I was thinking that the hardware I/O would reside in the application that renders the graphics in its own thread, but now I am thinking it might be better to put all the Hardware I/O comm in a seperate process and communicate between the two processes with some IPC protocol (not sure which one).

What do you guys recommend me doing. This would also be my first time writing a multi-process application.

Comment: [Real realtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing), or fast/interactive enough that people won't care/notice?

Comment: I would like it to be fast enough that I want notice any lag in the data.  Trying to replace my project car's instrument cluster with this application.

Comment: This is almost never not a mistake.  Best way to blow up an expensive rocket.

Answer (score 0):

I have written such things hundreds of times.  By far, the best solution is to split the dedicated hardware into two threads or tasks:

- one which does whatever realtime operations are needed
- another which responds to data queries and commands from the UI

These two threads cooperate with each other to maintain a consistent, semaphore-protected shared variable space.  The second thread does all its parsing and whatnot before locking the shared space, makes a copy of whatever it needs, and unlocks.  The goal is to limit the locking interval to as short a time as possible.  Oftentimes, it is practical to arrange all the shared variables into a single structure, and use a bulk `memcpy()`, even if only a few members are of interest.  The simpler this interaction, the better.

The UI contains

- screens which, when visible and active, cause periodic queries to the data module

Other architectures are possible, but whenever I've seen them, they have devolved into huge steaming masses of patches to work around synchronization and timing issues.

Comment: would doing it into threads (Gui and hardware separate threads) or spliting them into sepeerate processes be better. Is there an advantage over one or the other.  Like if on process crashes the other can start it back up again.

Comment: Depends on the platform.  For example, using Microsoft Windows, I would use threads in a single process due to its weaknesses with interprocess communication.  Using Linux, do it either way—whichever seems more natural to you.

Comment: Ok, I'm planning to use Minimal Ubuntu as my OS for its light weightness.  Hopefully this will help to improve the real-timeness of the application.